# Are simple algebraic groups absolutely simple?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field. By a simple algebraic group over $k$ I mean an affine group scheme $G$ of finite type over $k$ such that $G$ is connected, non-commutative and every normal closed subgroup of $G$ is trivial. I would like to know an example of a simple algebraic group such that the base extension $G_{\overline{k}}$ of $G$ to the algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$ is not simple anymore.

If $G$ is connected and non-commutative then also $G_{\overline{k}}$ is connected and non-commutative. So the problem is really about normal subgroups of $G_{\overline{k}}$ not being defined over $k$.

Comment: Your definition of simple does not quite agree with the usual one (which also has the subgroups be connected). Is that on purpose?

Comment: Yes this is on purpose. The ones you are referring to I would call "almost simple".

Comment: Btw, are you identifying the group with its points over the field, or are you considering it as a scheme? Because in the latter case, I can't think of any examples of such a group (at least not in positive characteristic). (By such a group, I mean one that is simple).

Comment: I am considering it as a scheme. I am mainly interested in characteristic zero. You can get a simple group by taking an almost simple group and then taking the quotient modulo the center.

Comment: I guess it is just not obvious to me why that results in a connected group, why the center is maximal among normal closed subgroups, or why this all works in characteristic $0$, when it fails in positive characteristic.

Comment: Any image of a connected group is connected. (Connected is the same as irreducible and I think you can check that purely topologically.) Any normal closed subgroup of an almost simple group is contained in the center: Let $N$ be a normal closed subgroup and $n\in N$. Consider the map $G\to G$, $g\mapsto gng^{-1}$. The image of this map is connect and lies in N, which is finite. Therefore the image is just $1$, showing that $n$ is in the center. What fails in positice characteristic?

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to figure out where this fails in positive characteristic (at least it seems to me that it must: in positive characteristic, if the group is simple, then the first Frobenius kernel would be trivial. But this would imply that there were no non-trivial reps of the Lie algebra of $G$ as a $p$-Lie algebra, and hence that this Lie algebra is trivial).

Comment: In positive characteristic one should probably assume that $G$ and also the normal subgroups are smooth.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $SL(d,\mathbb{C})$ as a real algebraic group (ie, replace each matrix entry with a $2 \times 2$ matrix representing a complex number with real entries). Then the complexification has the structure of $SL(d,\mathbb{C}) \times SL(d,\mathbb{C})$ and is hence $SL(d,\mathbb{C})$, considered as a group over $\mathbb{R}$, is not absolutely simple.